# Perl: What exactly is C<our>?

Tags: perl

I am in the process of teaching my self Perl. I am using the EPIC debugger in Eclipse. Whenever I have a var used only one time in a sub I get this warning:
*Typographical errors often show up as unique variable names.
If you had a good reason for having a unique name, then just mention it
again somehow to suppress the message.  The `C<our>` declaration is
provided for this purpose.*
What is `C<our>`? Standard searching was inconclusive.

Comment: When you say "standard searching was inconclusive", did you try typing [perldoc -f our](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html)?

Comment: @Ether - not every person knows about (or even has access to ) perldoc command line. Most people just Google.

Comment: @Cooter => while adding an `our` to the variable declaration may suppress the warning, the reason you are getting it is because the variable is only ever used once in your program.  This is probably an error unless you are playing games with symbolic references or direct symbol table access (which you shouldn't really be doing while learning the basics of the language).  Could you post the block of code generating the warning?

Comment: @DVK: I did also linked to the online documentation... but when would one not have the documentation installed locally?  ActivePerl has the perldocs internally, and any unix install should have the perldoc command.  (I ask a question about perldoc when I interview prospective hires... unless one is a *total* perl n00b, one should know where to find the documentation.)

Comment: @Ether - none of the Perl developers I ever known ever used command line perldoc. And 100% of them were Unix side developers. Heck, I was a not-so-bad Perl developer and I didn't know about the existence of perldoc *command* till I saw it mentioned on SO despite using the online version. In 2011, I would argue that judging "knowingh where to find documentation" by knowing a command line version of it is not a very reliable filter. Now, if they can't answer "on SO"... :)

Comment: @Ether: Debian-derived Linux distros have separate `perl` and `perl-doc` packages, of which only `perl` is installed by default, so many (most?) Debian-using Perl developers do not have the documentation installed locally.  (And, as per @DVK's experience, I tend to go first to google even if the docs are installed locally. General-purpose search tools tend to trump specialized search tools for most of us.)

Comment: @ether: I wasnt searching for 'our' I was searching for C<our> which explains why my searching was for naught (dont know much about POD). What a n00b thing to do!!! It'd be funnier if someone else did it besides me ---- but I can tell you that I use perldoc.perl.org quite a bit....

Comment: @Cooter: ah I see now!  Well then... :)  C<anything> is pod markup for "the stuff contained therein is code", but if you don't write pod you wouldn't necessarily know that.

Comment: @Eric:  When I'm 'roughing' in the code I tend to be var happy and then I go back over and clean up and reduce unneeded statements and vars. This was more of a curiosity on my part than a roadblock.-thx

Comment: @Cooter - BTW, when searching for syntax-heavy stuff like this (`C<out>`), one trick that MIGHT sometimes work is Google code search. No guarantees though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- As far as `C<>` part that may have confused you, it looks like EPIC took a text [in POD format](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) and printed it raw instead of rendering it from POD into a formatted text.

  `C<our>` in POD syntax means "Print text 'our' formatted as code", usually meaning mono-spaced font. This is similar to [StackOverflow's `` `our` `` backtick-surrounded format command](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your own question used.
- The error itself comes from Perl's [`diagnostics`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) module, which provides extended explanations for otherwise somewhat cryptic Perl warnings (in this case, "*Name "%s::%s" used only once: possible typo*"). As a matter of fact, judging from the POD formatting which confused you, EPIC probably uses the [source POD from which the above-linked "perldiag" document was generated](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JHI/perl-5.8.0/pod/perldiag.pod).
- If you're asking what `our` does, you should read [perldoc -f our](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) - it is a way to create an alias into a global variable effective in a given scope (see tchrist's asnwer for details).
- As far as googling technique in this case, when you're searching specifically for what you expect to be Perl keywords, it always pays to google for "perldoc someKeyword".

Comment: That is incorrect. `our` in no way declares a variable as part of the current package. It declares a lexical that’s part of the current **score**, providing an alias into the same-named package variable. But the lexical is part of scope, not a package, and thus retains its aliased binding even if you change packages. `package Outer; $Outer::Var = 10; our $Var; package Inner; $Inner::Var = 20; say $Var;` works just fine to get 10 printed, not 20. This also means you can’t do the normal lexical shadowing trick of `my $var = 10; { my $var = $var * 2; ... }`. See how all that works?

Comment: @tchrist - I hope you meant current **scope** and not current *score*, otherwise I'll be absolutely confused. If it was just a typo and not some deep perl term I never heard of before, you're absolutely right. My only excuse is that I never use "our" in such fancy ways (since most of my Perl code is largely OO where such approach would be bad design).

Comment: That was it..... I dunno nothing about POD and thats why I couldnt find anything when I searched for C<our>.... This is the kind of mistake that makes me want to calmly turn off the PC and walk away....    thx

Comment: @Cooter - and that's why SO exists :)  .... now if someone on SO only knew how to solve my gdb "identifier ???? in stack trace" issue... :)

Answer (score 5):

`our` is a lexically scoped alias to a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's a `Perl::Critic` message suggesting you can use `our $var;` for variable definition :-) for described reason.

Comment: Are you sure this is from Perl::Critic and not `diagnostics`?

Comment: `our` does not, strickly speaking, define a variable.  It provides a new lexically scoped alias to an existing global variable.  That means `my $x = 10` and `our $Big_X = 100` do very subtly different things: consider what happens when in another, perhaps nested scope we then have `my $x = 20` and `our $Big_X = 1_000`. That’s a brand new private variable named `$x`, but the package global `$Big_X` just had its value changed.